# Does javonet support java 9, 10, and 11

Tags: javonet

Does Javonet support Java 9, Java 10, and Java 11? I couldn't find any documentation supporting or refuting the more recent jdk versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Javonet both Javonet for Java developers and Javonet for .NET developers does support Java 9, 10 and 11.

In case of Javonet for .NET developers it is not supported within currently official build. Please contact Javonet technical support team at https://www.javonet.com/contact/ to get latest build with support for Java 9, 10 and 11. We will update this thread as soon as the build is released officially.

Comment: @Jonathan Sylvester if you work on custom build with performance improvements provided in other threads on SO, please mention that in the support ticket. Some of the custom build do have that support others will need to obtain new JAR. Works on new official package with all those improvements embedded are on final stage.

Comment: Would be good for Javonet to document this clearly in a 'Requirements' page on their website, as to what JDK & .NET versions are supported.